# How to allow negative values, xml schema?

Tags: xsd

```
<xs:element name="Quantity" minOccurs="1">
 <xs:simpleType>
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:maxLength value="10" /> 
  <xs:minLength value="1" /> 
  <xs:pattern value="[0-9]*" /> 
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: Why not just use `<xs:integer>`, then?

Answer (score 1):

Turning skaffmans comment into an answer: Choose integer for type.

```
<xs:element name="Quantity" type="xs:integer">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Adding to @Filburt's answer, you don't need to explicitly mention minOccurs="1" in such cases because by default minOccurs and maxOccurs are equal to 1.